# ASP MVC2 not showing google map on position

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, google-maps

i am using below code to show google map in asp.net MVC2:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
         var myOptions = {
             zoom: 8,
             center: myLatlng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
     });



    </script>
```

and my div is like this:

```
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:323; height:207;">
                            </div>
```

with above code it was not showing any google map but after referencing below link when i set its opsition:relative to off using firebug then its showing map otherwise not and also not at position where i placed my div but on left:0 and on top:0. please help me to show it on exact position and to make it visible:

[ASP.NET MVC 2 and Google Maps Javascript API Version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344743/asp-net-mvc-2-and-google-maps-javascript-api-version-3)

EDIT:
I am using vs2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **position:relative** CSS style rule is necessary, otherwise the map will be absolutely positioned on the left top of the screen.

I tried your code in an empty MVC 2 project and it works perfectly.

Comment: @tshao: but its not working on my side. please give me any hint what should i check.

Comment: @tshao: i have tried with new project also but same thing is there. not showing me any map. and when using firbug i am setting its postions:relative to off its showing me map on left:0 and top:0

Comment: I'm trying it in a VS2010 generated MVC 2 project in IE and Firefox. Let me try it on VS2008, see if there's any difference.

Comment: @tshao: i am using vs2010 only

Comment: @tshao: can u plez edit your answer and tell me exact position where u placed the code. like which code in head and which one in body. thanks a lot.i am using firefox 3.6

Comment: @Rajesh: Got it! Don't forget the 'px' for width/height -- <div id="map_canvas" style="width:323px; height:207px;"></div> :)

Comment: @tshao: i am using it with masterpage.